# Finding the lowest and largest number in a nested loop

Tags: java

```
    int smallest = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    int num;
    for (int row=1; row<=5; row++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Grades for student #" + row);
        
        num = (int)(Math.random()*50)+50;
        double total = 0;
        smallest = num;
        for (int col = 0; col<10; col++)
        {
            num = (int)(Math.random()*50)+50;
            System.out.print(num+ ", ");
            total += num*1.0;
        }
         
         System.out.println();
         double average = total/10;
          System.out.println("Average for student is " + 
         average);  
        if (num > largest) {
            largest = num;
        }
        if (num < smallest) {
            smallest = num;
        }
    }
  System.out.println("The largest score is:" + largest);
  System.out.println("The smallest score is : " + 
  smallest);
```

Trying to figure print out the lowest and largest score for random numbers generated in a loop for 5 students. The code is printing out the wrong number for lowest score.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest and largest number are initialized with 0. They should be initialized with the first value instead.

Comment: The logic being, of course, that unless there are negative grades, the default (0) will remain the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this part inside the nested loop.

```
    if (num > largest) {
        largest = num;
    }
    if (num < smallest) {
        smallest = num;
    }
```

Otherwise they are only comparing `num` of the last column of each row.

Answer (score 0):

below is a code snippet of finding the largest and smallest value from a loop.you may adjust it with your requirement.

```
int minMax = 0;
int smallest = 0;
int largest = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= totalNumbers; i++){
    System.out.print("Number " + i + ": ");
    int inputNumbers = console.nextInt();
    if(inputNumbers > largest){
        largest = inputNumbers;
    } else if (inputNumbers < smallest){
        smallest = inputNumbers;
   }
}
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Smallest = " + smallest);
System.out.println("Largest = " + largest);
```